# Google spreadsheet : Basic Sum by row

Tags: sum, spreadsheet

newb in spreadsheets

I want the E3 field to be the sum of C3+D3, then E4 = E4+D4.... each line like that (from row 3 to 100).  Of course I dont want to set each line individually.

How can I do that ?  Probably pretty basic stuff but all the answers I tried did'nt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the formula box for `E3`, type:

```
=sum(C3+D3)
```

Then hit enter.

To copy this down, click `E3`, click and drag the blue square in the bottom right hand corner of the cell and drag this down the `E` column.